# automate tests for CSS and visual abnomalities with python selenium?

Tags: python, css, testing, webdriver

I want to write a python script that can check/test the css on a website.

1. selenium webdriver is equipped with `value_of_css_property(property_name)`, which can be used to extract value of a css property for an element. This can be compared with an expected value. The selenium can then interact and if required record the changes in property and again compare with the expected value.
2. or capture screenshot of an element and then use PIL to compare the screenshot with the expected one (something what python [needle](https://github.com/python-needle/needle) does),however since size and placement change according to resolution/device I don't know how feasible this approach is.

any thoughts as to what can be done from above or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We've been using [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/) for this particular "visual testing" problem:

> Layout testing seemed always a complex task. Galen Framework offers a
>   simple solution: test location of objects relatively to each other on
>   page. Using a special syntax and comprehensive rules you can describe
>   any layout you can imagine
>
> Galen Framework is designed with responsiveness in mind. It is easy to
>   set up a test for different browser sizes. Galen just opens a browser,
>   resizes it to a defined size and then tests the page according to
>   specifications

We are writing Galen tests in JavaScript, there is a [Python port](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/galenpy), but not sure how up-to-date it is.

---

`needle` is an awesome tool, but images overall are "clumsy" and hard to deal with and maintain. If you make your sizes and resolutions concrete, then it would make things easier.

---

Using `value_of_css_property()` is always an option, but it might not scale well and it would be challenging to avoid violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Think of some sort of an *abstraction layer* over checking your CSS properties. For instance, have a "style" config in your tests with pre-defined styles with a number of required properties (e.g. every "submit" button in your application needs to have `btn` and `btn-primary` classes and needs to have a specific size, font size, background and border colors)..then you can configure a pre-defined style for every [page object](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) field in a page object..just thoughts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, your response was really informative and helpful. Would be testing Galen and as you mentioned checking the rendering or the overal layout of html in an automated fashion is something very challenging,as the results I am getting by methods still required manual touch points. Thanks a lot again :-)